# Looking for a function with some characteristics

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm looking for an "error" function $g(x), x>0$, comparing a real value $x$ with 1, and with the following characteristics:

- $g'(1) = 0$ - A local minimum at 1
- $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}({g(x)\over x^2})=1$ - For large values of $x$, the function should tend to $x^2$
- $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0+}g(x)=+\infty$ - For small values of $x$, the error is $\infty$
- $g(x)$ should be continuous, n-order derivable (at least 1)
- Rather fast to compute

I plan to use it in a numerical multi-variable solver that minimize some function, and works better with some sort of "quadratic" form (hence the second point). The error function is computing by summing over $g$, comparing a list of normalized values with 1.

I tested the function $1/x+(x-1)^2$ with a scaling factor of $\beta\approx 1.2972$ (the local minimum), but I'm not really happy with it as it lack some kind of "symmetry" around 1, and the $\beta$ value seems a bit magic. I'm wondering if a function based on logarithm would not be better for symmetry around 1 (by symmetry I mean that the error between $x$ and 1 should be the same as the error between $1/x$ and 1).

Comment: How about $x^2+1/x^2$?

Comment: @Arthur Looks great indeed, I like the symmetry and the general form.

Comment: I like it even better when you write it in the form $x^2+x^{-2}-2$ to emphasis the symmetry (I offset by -2 just for having the minimum at zero, but that's not a requirement).

Comment: Well, it's perfect: $g(x) = g(1/x)$, that's what I really need. Thanks. Write an answer, I'll mark it resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x^2+1/x^2$ has the proper asymptotic and symmetric properties.